# Need help using subset within lineplot.CI function in R

Tags: r, subset

I am a statistics and an R novice who is learning alot about both using RStudio.  I have a imported a dataframe with the data in long form for mixed effects ANOVA on a longitudinal balanced study design.  I have the following headings on my data:  Treatment, Subject, Date, Age, and Volume.  I have no trouble plotting either by Age group alone or Treatment group alone with the following code:

```
lineplot.CI(mri$Date,mri$Les.V.PD, mri$Age,main="Mean Lesion Volume by Age Group on PD Sequences",xlab="MRI timepoints (months post treatment)", ylab="Lesion Volume(cm^3)")
```

I would like to plot, using lineplot.CI with Date on the x axis, 4 lines: 2yr Treatment, 6 yr Treatment, 2 yr Control, and 6 yr Control.  This code results in a line plot by Age group only:

```
lineplot.CI(mri$Date,mri$Les.V.PD,mri$Age,subset=mri$Treatment %in% c("MSC","Control"),main="Mean Lesion Volume by Age Group on PD Sequences", xlab="MRI timepoints (months post treatment)", ylab="Lesion Volume(cm^3)")
```

This code gives the same line plot as the above code:

```
lineplot.CI(mri$Date,mri$Les.V.PD,mri$Age,subset= .(mri$Treatment == "MSC" | mri$Treament == "Control"),main="Mean Lesion Volume by Age Group on PD Sequences",xlab="MRI timepoints (months post treatment)", ylab="Lesion Volume(cm^3)")
```

I have also tried various renditions of this code:

```
lineplot.CI(mri$Date,mri$Les.V.PD,mri$Age,subset(mri,Treatment == "MSC"|Treatment =="Control"),main="Mean Lesion Volume by Age Group on PD Sequences",xlab="MRI timepoints (months post treatment)", ylab="Lesion Volume(cm^3)")
```

or

```
lineplot.CI(mri$Date,mri$Les.V.PD,mri$Age,subset(mri, !(Treatment == "MSC"|Treatment == "Control")),main="Mean Lesion Volume by Age Group on PD Sequences",xlab="MRI timepoints (months post treatment)", ylab="Lesion Volume(cm^3)")
```

and get the following errors:

```
Error in subset.default(mri$Treatment == "MSC" | mri$Treament == "Control") :
```

argument "subset" is missing, with no default

```
Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

I know the sciplot package documentation that subset is included within lineplot.CI but all of the examples I have seen show subset=NULL.  I would prefer to continue using lineplot.CI because of the automatic insertion of error bars and the fact that I am unfamiliar with ggplot2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
lineplot.CI(xField, yField, group=gField, data=subset(dataSource, 
                                               field1=="value1" | field2=="value2"))
```

The author of the question tries to use the lineplot.CI command with the parameter "subset". Instead of this, it is possible to use the parameter "data" with the value of a subset.

So, instead of to use

lineplot.CI (..., subset=(datasource, select expression), ...)

the idea is to use:

lineplot.CI(..., data=subset(datasource, select expression), ...)

This alternative way worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @hvescovi. Would you mind expanding this a little & providing some explanation? What is the "[]'s"?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck into the same problem... After some research I figured out that [lineplot.CI documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sciplot/docs/lineplot.CI) not only lacks lots of useful information but also presents some functions as if they were part of it, when those are **external methods** actually, which can be **combined** with lineplot.CI in order to reach a specific result.
*subset* is a base function of the R environment, therefore it does not depend on lineplot.CI.
[This link](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) provides further information on it, but a better/deeper description can be found at the offline documentation provided within the R package. On your R command line type

```
help(subset)
```

and you'll see interesting ways of applying it upon data frames.

Assign your newly created subset to the *data* parameter of lineplot.CI and you'll get the results you want. For instance (based on your data):

```html
df <- subset(
        mri, 
        Treatment %in% c("MSC", "Control"), 
        select = c( Treatment, Subject, Date, Age, Volume )
      )
lineplot.CI(
   data = df,
   x.factor = Date, 
   response = Les.V.PD,
   group = Age,
   main="Mean Lesion Volume by Age Group on PD Sequences",
   xlab="MRI timepoints (months post treatment)", 
   ylab="Lesion Volume(cm^3)"
)
```